# Date range pickers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-1.5, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Can anyone suggest some good date range picker with angularjs which can work without range also? So, flexible to use in different use cases and customizable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this javascript component

http://www.daterangepicker.com/

**OR**

use this angularjs component

http://fragaria.github.io/angular-daterangepicker/

**both of them designed to work with the Bootstrap framework**

Comment: It uses jQuery... I do not like mix Angularjs with jQuery. It is like mixing honey with vinegar, you can...

Answer (score -2):

other : https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker

> This is an Angular 2, 4, 5+ port of the popular Date Range Picker for Bootstrap http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: But not Angular***JS*** ?

Comment: OP has specifically requested components for AngularJS, what you have recommended seems to be only available for Angular